# Paintwork damage

Tags: paint, paint-scratches

I want to learn how to repair paintwork damage on a car.

Anyone here who can provide me with step by step instructures on how to repair the following type of damaged paintwork?

The damage can be seen on the left hand side:
[image]

Here are some closeups:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a badly oxidized clearcoat. The state the paint looks to be in pretty much means that the only cure is a respray. To make matters a bit more interesting, the paint looks like a silver metallic which is much harder to match than a plain colour and will require additional blending in into the surrounding areas like front wings.

If you have never done any paintwork before, this is not something to start experimenting on, the result will look worse than it does now. Assuming the bonnet goes back onto a car, get a decent pro in instead.

As to the process, you're basically looking at the following:

- Sand the area to be painted, the old paint needs a good scuffing and you most likely have to do the whole bonnet. If it's already oxidised the rest of the paint isn't far behind.
- If you find any dents, stone chips and other imperfections, treat them.
- Spray the appropriate filler/primer coat over the existing paint to isolate it from the new paint and sand it. Most likely you'll find some additional dents or high spots, or you accidentally sand through the primer, so you'll repeat this a couple of times.
- Spray a couple of layers of the base coat. Given that it's a metallic paint, you have to be careful doing that so you get even coats and no areas with higher paint buildup because that will change the colour.
- Wait for the paint to dry, then spray a few layers of clearcoat, again ensuring they're even, with no runs, dust inclusions, orange peel etc etc

You also will have to feather in the paint into the surrounding paintwork to achieve a gradual transition from one panel to the other, otherwise the newly painted panel will stand out like a sore thumb.

There's also the issue of paint, depending on your local laws you might not be able to either purchase the appropriate paint or spray it yourself depending on its toxicity. You also really, really don't want to spray two pack paint that uses isocyanide hardeners without full respiratory gear and hopefully in a paint booth with appropriate filters. That stuff is really, really bad for your health.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes! You'll get the best result from completely respraying. I'll admit to being too lazy to type up the whole process, but only because Google will literally give you millions of sites telling you what to do. The short answer is to sand it down, then respray, paying attention to doing every step thoroughly.

Don't try to get away with trying to only fix the trouble area. If paint damage is as big as that, you'll want to do the whole panel if you want a uniform finish.

Watch these as a start:

[Respray a car and color change DIY](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnYBhBbgvK8)

[How to patch rust](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-JFTnnZgBE)

Comment: I don't know what to type into Google, as I don't know what that type of paint damage is called.  However, when you say sand, do you mean sand down the whole thing to metal?

Comment: To the base-coat should be fine. I've added two youtube links for you to watch.